How can I find the highest ancestor in a tree?
I have the following 2 SQL tables
CREATE TABLE tag_hierarchies (
    ancestor_id integer NOT NULL,
    descendant_id integer NOT NULL,
    generations integer NOT NULL
);

Where generation 0 represents a root
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    name VARCHAR
);

I'm unable to generate a query that would return the lowest generation (ie. highest ancestor) per tree. Example trees:
a/b/c/d and e would be represented in the database as:
tag_hierarchies



ancestor_id
descendant_id
generation




84
84
0


85
85
0


84
85
1


86
86
0


85
86
1


84
86
2


87
87
0


86
87
1


85
87
2


84
87
3


88
88
0



and
tags



id
name




84
a


85
b


86
c


87
d


88
e



I want to run a query that would return the unique lowest generation (ie. highest ancestor) per tree. So this query will get a base scope of tags and return unique tags. As an example if I run it with b, c & e it would return b & e. Since b has a lower generation between b & c and e is already a root.

If you add (89,89,0),(88,89,1) and (89,'f') what you get for ('c','f')?

That's one of the primary uses of recursive CTE's. There are also pre-built and highly optimised functions in pgrouting extension and a whole Cypher query language in Apache AGE.

Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (You can delete the irrelevant tag.)

@jarlh I'm using postgresql. I'm not sure if something DB specific should be used here, a typical query can do the job, no?

@bwaw, in many cases yes. But not always. And it's good to know for other readers with similar problems.

Assuming that

"...lowest generation (ie. highest ancestor) per tree ..."

means how deep in hierarchy id appears as descendant, then you could create a cte (grid) to get the lowest generation per tree:
Updated code (after clarifications in the comments):
WITH
  grid AS
    ( Select     t.id, t.name, 
                 Max(h.generations) as lowest_generation,
                 Case When Max(h.generations) > 0 Then Min(h.ancestor_id) Else t.id End as root_ancestor
      From       tags t
      Inner Join tag_hierarchies h ON( h.descendant_id = t.id )
      Group By   t.id, t.name
    ) 
--    Checking grid resultset 
Select     g.*
From       grid  g
Order By   g.lowest_generation, g.id

/*      R e s u l t :
id  name    lowest_generation  root_ancestor
--  ------  -----------------  -------------
84  a                       0             84
88  e                       0             88
85  b                       1             84
86  c                       2             84
87  d                       3             84        */

... now if you want to do it on specific tags as mentioned in the question ...

As an example if I run it with b, c & e it would return b & e. Since b has a lower generation between b & c and e is already a root.

... then put your tags (b, c, e) as filter in Where clause of the grid cte and build the Where clause of main sql to filter just the rows with root tags and the tag(s) with the lowest_generation greather than 0 (root) ...
WITH
  grid AS
    ( Select     t.id, t.name, 
                 Max(h.generations) as lowest_generation,
                 Case When Max(h.generations) > 0 Then Min(h.ancestor_id) Else t.id End as root_ancestor
      From       tags t
      Inner Join tag_hierarchies h ON( h.descendant_id = t.id )
      Where      t.name IN('b', 'c', 'e')
      Group By   t.id, t.name
    ) 

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select     g.id, g.name
From       grid   g  
Where      g.lowest_generation IN(Select Min(lowest_generation) 
                                  From grid 
                                  Where root_ancestor = g.root_ancestor
                                  Group By root_ancestor)
Order By   g.id

--  R e s u l t : 
--  (for grid Where clause)  Where      t.name IN('b', 'c', 'e')
id  name
--  ----
85  b
88  e

--  R e s u l t : 
--  for grid with no Where clause
id  name
--  ----
84  a
88  e

See the fiddle here.
NOTE:
The code is the same for both - mysql and postgresql... as well as for almost every dialect (Oracle, SQL Sever, SQLite, MariaDB, ...)

thank you very much for taking the time to write this thorough answer. But I think it's missing something that I can seem to fill. This solution does not take into consideration the relativity inside the tree. For example, if run the exact same query but with Where t.name IN('a', 'b', 'c', 'e') it will return "a, b & e" even though "b" shouldn't be returned because "a" is an ancestor.

@bmaw You said that for b,c,e you want e cause it's root, so I thought that root should be selected with first lowest generation. And a is root to, just like e the only difference is that e doesn't have descendants yet. Sorry. It is night here, I can fix it in the morning, though.

Yes, that's true for b,c,e - (b, e) should be returned because because "e" is the highest ancestor relative to its tree. Further examples: 1. Running this query on the data without any where filtering should essentially return all roots (a, e). 2. Running this query on the same data but with the filtering for (c, e) should return (c, e). 3. Running the query on the data but with filtering for (a, c, e) should also return (a, e) (since a & c belong to the same tree but "a" is an ancestor to c). Again, thank you!

@bmaw Just posted the updated code. Added one more column in grid cte (root_ancestor) and changed Main SQL's Where clause.

Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! You sir are great help

@bmaw You are welcome. I'm glad it helped you...
